# Composite C1 generates crazy amount of cache dlls

Tags: asp.net, c1-cms

I'm running an older version of Composite C1: Composite C1 3.2 Patch 3, Build no. 3.2.4681.14221

I've noticed on the live site that a crazy 26,000+ dll files have accumulated in App_Data/Composite/Cache/Assemblies folder. Is there a way to configure Composite C1 to clean-up after itself? They're only 5 KB in size each, but amount to over 116 MB combined and take ages to backup when backing up the whole site.

Comment: Setup a scheduled task on your windows server to clear up this folder. C1 4.2 has built functionality to clear this folder at startup.

Comment: Thanks for info. Hoping to upgrade, but a lot of custom code to migrate so not managed to found the time yet. The site is on shared hosting so no option to setup a scheduled task.

Comment: I can recommend looking at HangFire (http://hangfire.io/) which has a Composite C1 datastore package https://bitbucket.org/burningice/hangfire.compositec1. This allows you to schedule recurring jobs so you ie. cleans up the cache folder once a day.

Comment: Thanks Pauli - looks perfect. A good solution to know about regardless!